# How do I cut off part of an element, but keep it available in the DOM?

Tags: html, css

This is my goal:

[image: what I want]

The arrows cycle through the boxes by sliding them left and right - but the Javascript solution for this is beyond the scope of this question.

This is what I currently have:

[image: what I have]

As you see, the 6th box naturally floats over into the new line. What I need is to display whatever part of it can fit to the right of the 5th box. Presumably there should be some way to allow the container div (`#toplist-saved`) to have more width than its parent (`#toplist-inner`), and then hiding the overflow on its parent should do the trick. I could resolve this by setting the container width to some fixed huge width like 1000%, instead I'd like it to have only the minimal width required to hold the boxes without floating them over into a new line. Is this possible? This is the current HTML:

```
<div id="toplist">
    <div style="display: block;" id="toplist-inner">
        <div style="display: block;" id="toplist-saved">
            <h5>Saved Reports:</h5> 
            <div class="toplist-box">
                <div class="toplist-box-inner">
                    <div class="toplist-box-title">
                        <img src="img/desktop_grey.jpg"> Sample Report #1
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-cog toplist-box-settings"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash toplist-box-delete"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toplist-box">
                <div class="toplist-box-inner">
                    <div class="toplist-box-title">
                        <img src="img/desktop_grey.jpg"> Sample Report #2
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-cog toplist-box-settings"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash toplist-box-delete"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toplist-box">
                <div class="toplist-box-inner">
                    <div class="toplist-box-title">
                        <img src="img/desktop_grey.jpg"> Sample Report #3
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-cog toplist-box-settings"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash toplist-box-delete"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toplist-box">
                <div class="toplist-box-inner">
                    <div class="toplist-box-title">
                        <img src="img/desktop_grey.jpg"> Sample Report #4
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-cog toplist-box-settings"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash toplist-box-delete"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toplist-box">
                <div class="toplist-box-inner">
                    <div class="toplist-box-title">
                        <img src="img/desktop_grey.jpg"> Sample Report #5
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-cog toplist-box-settings"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash toplist-box-delete"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="toplist-box">
                <div class="toplist-box-inner">
                    <div class="toplist-box-title">
                        <img src="img/desktop_grey.jpg"> Sample Report #6
                    </div>
                    <i class="fa fa-cog toplist-box-settings"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-trash toplist-box-delete"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="splitter"></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#toplist {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 34;
}

#toplist-inner {
    background: #f3f6fb;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#toplist-saved {
    display: none;
    width: 1000%;
}

#toplist-saved h5 {
    color: #0c5f9e;
}

.toplist-box-inner {
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 20px 30px 0;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 60px;
}

.toplist-box-settings {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toplist-box-delete {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toplist-box-title {
    color: #757575;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toplist-box-title img {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: A Demo would be useful but using `white-space:nowrap` on inline-block elements combined with `overflow:hidden` or `scroll` is a common method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do in your case:

Inside the container I would add another container which will hold all your "boxes". Those boxes will have `display:inline-block` insteed of float, that way you can add to this container `white-space:nowrap`to avoid the boxes to jump to the next line if no room enough. Then adding `overflow:hidden` to the container will "hide" any box outside.

Finally I will wrap again all the boxes into another container which won't have any css but will make the buttoms work as you will change the margin-left of this container each time you click on the buttoms like this:

```
$('.left').on('click', function(){    
    $('.margin-boxes').animate({marginLeft: '-=200px'}, 500);
  })

$('.right').on('click', function(){    
    $('.margin-boxes').animate({marginLeft: '+=200px'}, 500);
  })
```

You can add the margin to your first box and It may work the same, but I think it's cleaner to add this `margin-boxes`container.

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e1uzh3ns/4/)**

**Edit**: there's a problem though. you should add javascrit way that the `margin-left`of the container should never be positive or lower than -600px (-600px in my fiddle example with my boxes and margins) to avoid keep "scrolling" when you already seign your last box. It should not be very difficult to make it. I would do it but I can't stay at computer anymore till tonight.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'll figure out the details myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you want, but `overflow: auto;` combined with `overflow-x: hidden;` lets you get the functionality of `overflow: auto;` without the scroll bar.

This way you can move what's visible in the frame using the javascript functions you want, without having the scroll bar visible. I made a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkdbfprq/9/.

Comment: This still relies on the 1000% width that I set for testing. See without that: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkdbfprq/10/ I don't want to set a fixed width like that, that's the point of my question.